# Nginx server IP on droplet redirect to specific domain

Tags: node.js, nginx, server, vps

I have 2 domains running with nginx on a DigitalOcean Droplet

Domain1 is an node app proxypassing to localhost:3000.
Works great!

Domain2 is a static site working great too.

However whenever I load the server IP (without the port 3000), I always get redirected to domain1 (node app).

Domain1 is a sort of a private site, whereas domain2 is a public blog.

My question is what do I have to change for people to get redirected to domain2 whenever they load the IP in order to protect domain1 from beeing easily reachable. (The VPS IP is easy to look up)

Here are the "sites-available" files :

Node App :

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;


server_name www.domain1.com domain1.com;

# and redirect to the https host (declared below)
return 301 https://domain1.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;

    ssl on;
    # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';


    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

And the static one :

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;


   server_name www.domain2.com domain2.com;

   root /var/www/html/domain2;
   index index.html index.htm;


   return 301 https://domain2.com$request_uri;
}

server {

   listen [::]:443 ssl;
   listen 443 ssl;

   root /var/www/html/domain2;

   index index.html index.htm;

   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

Any help/hint is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So both your domains are listening on port 80.  When your nginx server receives a request, it then checks the domain before determining its route... but because there is no domain to check when you just type in the ip address, it will default to the first listed server (which i'm guessing is domain1)

you can circumvent this by declaring a default server, or switching the order in which they are listed.

I hope i could be of help. A nice little reference http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: Hey Aldose, thank you very much for the help. Got it working as I should be thanks to your hint. Again thanks and have a great day!